# get data of last 5min candle of yesterday day new york session

Tags: pine-script

I have searched for this Question but didn't any clue...
I want to get data of last 5 min candle of the last day of new york session which is 22:55-23:00 UTC +3 for me

I need the data to plot 3 lines(H,L,C) of last day range but the close must be NY close
I use this code but the close is not what I want:

```
[Daily_pdo,Daily_pdh,Daily_pdl,Daily_pdc,Daily_pdt,Daily_end] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", [open[1],high[1],low[1],close[1],time[1],time_close[0]])
```

then I must do this for last Week and last Month.
thanks a lot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The time function in pinescript are based on the time of the provider of the data, here FXOpen in your case.
So if you ask for open[1] you will have the answer in the data's provider time, which is different from yours.